Azure release pipeline's deployment to functionApp is stalling
using Azure release pipeline , deploying the function app using the task : https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureFunctionAppV1/README.md
It appears that the Azure release pipeline’s deployment to functionApp is stalling. Please find below screenshot , it runs for one hour and cancel itself
Error Log:

Attempt 1 to 4
##[error]Error: Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Conflict (CODE: 409)
Attempt8
[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
[warning]Can't find loc string for key: KuduStackTraceURL
[error]KuduStackTraceURL https://$func*****:@****.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace
##[error]Error: Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND func--01.scm.azurewebsites.net


The same code is being deployed to several hundreds of function apps. Though it takes time for retries, it is deployed.
Could you help in this regards.
Tell me if you require any additional information regarding any of the mandatory logs.

According to the official doc Capabilities and limitations, for the MS-hosted agent in a private project:

One free parallel job that can run for up to 60 minutes each time, until you've used 1,800 minutes (30 hours) per month. You can pay for additional capacity per parallel job. Paid parallel jobs remove the monthly time limit and allow you to run each job for up to 360 minutes (6 hours).

So your release pipeline runs for one hour and cancel itself. If your pipeline needs to run more than 60 minutes, you can pay for parallel jobs or use a self-hosted agent to run your pipeline.
For error Conflict (CODE: 409), it occurs when there is already an ongoing operation and you tried to perform another operation while the previous operation is not completed.
For Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND, it could be due to several reasons. For example, the ILB ASE not having the required entries on internal DNS, or your app is running in an ASE, which network access is isolated, and you access it using an agent outside the network.
You can try to deploy your function app using Azure CLI on your local machine and check if it has the same error or not. So that you can know whether it's related to your app or the pipeline.
